# Adding images to Vue Select dropdown?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-select

I am using `vue-select` component as my dropdowns and giving it `:options` as the data to put in the dropdown.  I am using it for a credit card dropdown right now and want to add the card type image in in each dropdown row.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the [scoped `option` slot](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Advanced/Templating.html) that `vue-select` provides for creating custom dropdown templates.

Assuming that your `options` data looked like this:

```
options: [
  {
    title: "Visa",
    cardImage: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/linktoimage.png"
  },
  {
    title: "Mastercard",
    cardImage: "https://codeclimate.com/github/sagalbot/linktoimage.png"
  }
];
```

Then you could use it as such:

```
<v-select :options="options" label="title">
  <template slot="option" slot-scope="option">
      <img :src="option.cardImage" />
      {{ option.title }}
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Ana, question.  This works great to display images next to the dropdown but when selecting the dropdown option, the selected one loses the image

Comment: @RohimL So far, I've only worked with adding images to the dropdown. I'm not sure if you can customize the selected option as well. So far I didn't see any props that we could use to do this.

Comment: You can use the selected-option slot to include an image in the selected item.

```lang-xml
            <template slot="selected-option" slot-scope="option">
                <div style="background-color: #212121; width: 155px; min-height: 34px; display: flex">
                    <img height="28" :src="option.image"/>
                    <span style="color: white; position: relative; margin: 5px;">{{ option.label }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>
```